# Masking of email address using reg expression

Tags: javascript, regex, email, masking

Trying to develop masking for email address using reg expression but not able to achieve the desired result.

Input : harrypotter@howarts.com

After masking I am looking for result something like this:

```
Output: "ha*****er@how*****.com"
```

What I tried is this reg expression:

```
(?<=.)[^@\n](?=[^@\n]*?[^@\n]@)|(?:(?<=@.)|(?!^)\G(?=[^@\n]*$)).(?=.*\.)

h*********r@h******.com
```

Comment: What is the conditions? 2 first and last charaters before @ and 3 aftrer not masked? What about email with 4 or less chrecters before @?

Comment: (?<=..)[^@\n](?=[^@\n]*?[^@\n]{2}@)|(?:(?<=@...)|(?!^)\G(?=[^@\n]*$)).(?=.*\.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs some clarification. Here is an answer making some assumptions:

- keep 2 leading and trailing chars of the name part (before `@`)
- keep 3 leading chars of the domain part (after `@`) until `.` and TLD (top level domain)
- replace with three asterisks `***` to more effectively obscure the address (better than exact number of chars replaced)
- no replacement for short names and domains.

Code with examples:

```js
[ `harrypotter@hogwarts.com`,
  `harry@hogwarts.com`,
  `tim@hogwarts.com`,
  `harrypotter@cia.gov`
].forEach(str => {
  let result = str
    .replace(/^(..).+?(?=..@)/, '$1***')
    .replace(/(@...).+?(?=\.\w+$)/, '$1***');
  console.log(str + ' => ' + result);
});
```

Output:

```
harrypotter@hogwarts.com => ha***er@hog***.com
harry@hogwarts.com => ha***ry@hog***.com
tim@hogwarts.com => tim@hog***.com
harrypotter@cia.gov => ha***er@cia.gov
```

Notice that there are two `.replace()` because one or the other replacement may fail if too short. If you combine into one the whole regex would fail if one side fails.

Explanation of first regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(..)` -- capture group 1 for two chars
- `.+?` -- non-greedy scan for 1+ chars
- `(?=..@)` -- positive lookahead for two chars and `@`

Notice that we could replace the capture group 1 with a positive lookbehind. This is however not supported by all browsers, notably Safari, hence better to void.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mystring='harrypotter@howarts.com';
mystring.replace(/(^[^@]{2})?(@[^.]{3})?.(?=([^@]{2,}@)|([^@]*\.[^.]+$))/gm,'$1$2*');
```

This is mostly about what you want to keep, not what you want to mask.  The approach is to replace every single scanned character with an asterisk one at a time, while skipping the delimiters and the characters around them.

The first two paren sets are optional capture groups that recognize delimiters (begin-string & @) and the 2 or 3 characters to keep after.  They get put into capture groups 1 & 2 and will be null unless the scanner is at that point in the string.

The next part `.` is the actual character to be replaced with an asterisk.

The rest is a lookahead to ensure the characters you want to retain appearing before a delimiter are skipped over.  (You only replace if there are at least two chars and one @ somewhere to your right, or if there is no @ and a dot followed by a domain name to your right.)

Here it is in action on Regex101:
[image]

Comment: It does the magic to some extend but number of masked character has to be 5 on each side that is still the issue. "ha*****er@how*****.com". Any input on that.